# Meaning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am unable to understand the meaning of following sentence:

***About Fran***, she can call in to see your grandmother, can't she?
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those contexts, "about" is a way for the speaker to bring up a subject for discussion. Sometimes it will be preceded by "Oh", which serves a similar function: "I-am-about-to-change-the-subject" or "I-just-remembered-something-I-wanted-to-tell-you". As your text says, "when a speaker is *orienting* a listener".

> Oh, about that movie you mentioned to me a couple of weeks ago...I did
>   manage to see it. It was just as good as you said it would be.